# PHP+AJAX: How to make toggle for sorting data?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, toggle

I have a very simple page, where is the list of users from database. On this page is a table containing these information, with **name**, **surname**, **age**, **city**.

I would like to make a toggle, when I click on the **name** title and all names would be sorted as **ASC** and then when I click again on the **name** title, all names would be sorted as **DESC** in the real time.

Could you give me please an advice how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: There are dozens of plugins for this that use AJAX or simple jQuery to handle the sorting/pagination. Top of my head: http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/03/table-sorter/

Comment: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Datatables Plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) for jQuery.  I use it extensively for exactly this, and it's fairly easy to implement.  The forums get pretty good response times too.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly you should consider JavaScript/jQuery for this:

[Table Sorter for jQuery](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)